# unable to add coyote-time function

Tags: game-development, godot, platform, coyote

I want to add coyote time in my 2d platformer in godot but I was unable to make it work.
here is my code, I learned GDscript 2 weeks ago and i am by no mean an expert
I tried changing the code order which just made the code break many times with no results, coyote time never did work
here is the code if you find any mistake or something that can be improved, I would love to read it even if it's not about coyote time.
extends KinematicBody2D

```
const UP = Vector2(0,-1)
const GRAVITY = 9
const SPEED = 150
const JUMP_HEIGHT = -400

var motion = Vector2()
var coyote_time
var is_jumping = false
var was_on_floor = is_on_floor()

func _ready():
    coyote_time = Timer.new()
    coyote_time.one_shot = true
    coyote_time.wait_time = 2.0
    add_child(coyote_time)
    $AnimationTree.active = true

func _physics_process(delta):
    motion.y += GRAVITY
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        motion.x = SPEED
        $Sprite.flip_h = false
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/state/current", 1)
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        motion.x = -SPEED
        $Sprite.flip_h = true
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/state/current", 1)
    else:
        motion.x = 0
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/state/current", 0)
    if coyote_time.is_stopped():
     motion.y += GRAVITY

    if is_on_floor():
        is_jumping = false
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
            is_jumping = true
            motion.y = JUMP_HEIGHT
    elif not is_on_floor() and was_on_floor and not is_jumping and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
            coyote_time.start()
            is_jumping = true
            motion.y = JUMP_HEIGHT
        
    else:
        if motion.y < 0:
            $AnimationTree.set("parameters/state/current", 2)
        else:
            $AnimationTree.set("parameters/state/current", 3)
    
    
    motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2.UP)
    pass
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable `was_on_floor`? It never changes value in the script, so if the player starts in the air the condition before `coyote_time.start()` will always be false.

Comment: Also, note that `motion.y += GRAVITY` appears twice in your script